# Automatic generation of UV maps

Tags: uv-mapping

Given an arbitrary triangle mesh, is it possible to automatically generate a UV mapping for it, and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: Yes, but it won't be pretty.

Explaination: While there *are* [algorithms](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Create-UVs--Automatic-Mapping-htm.html) to automagically UV map polygon soup, the mapping probably wont be ideal. UV mapping is an art really. Choosing where to hide the seams and where to put them to limit stretching and optimize texture space.

That said, there *are* lots of tools that can make manual UV mapping a heck of a lot easier. For example: http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Create-UVs--Automatic-Mapping-htm.html

Comment: Well, there are *quite* a bit more and *quite* a bit more advanced algorithms for mesh parameterization than what you linked to, so I wouldn't really subscribe to the idea that it *"won't be pretty"*, let alone such a short answer that barely touches the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Could you elaborate/link any of those algorithms? I will be happy to add more to the answer.

Comment: Not at the moment really.

Comment: @RichieSams: A very popular algorithm that quickly gained popularity is the least sqares conformal maps algorithm: https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall09/Levy02.pdf